# exec task with output argument using a property doesn't seem to work

Tags: ant, exec

I'm running an exec task with an output argument that uses a property value

```
<exec executable="cmd" resultproperty="runStatus" output="${logFolder}/soapui.log" error="${logFolder}/soapui-errors.log">
```

When running it doesn't do anything. If I however hardcode the output location `output="C:\a.txt"` it works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. At the same time `error="${logFolder}/soapui-errors.log"` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Try to add `append="true"`. Is it better?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Works for me.

Comment: Not an ant problem. Check file permissions/accesses if the file is open somewhere else etc.

Comment: @ Alex K I've tried append with no success.
@ FailedDev So basically that `${logFolder}` DIR does not exist and usually is created when soapUI outputs its logs there... so I assumed that soapUI would create the DIR for this output file too but it doesn't. Fixed by creating DIR beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to FailedDev for this one.

Basically the issue was with the `${logFolder}` not yet existing as it only gets created by soapUI to store logs. I assumed that soapUI would create the directory to store the `output` logs but I was wrong.

A simple `mkdir` task fixed this issue.